# Spinning charged sphere, magnetic energy

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, magnetic-moment, electromagnetic-induction

I have a question about this task:

> Consider a thin spherical shell of dielectric which has a radius R and rotates with an angular welocity $\omega$. Suppose that the mass of the shell is negligible.
>
> b) A constant torque $N$ is applied parallel to $\omega$. How long does it take for the shell to stop?

In the solution they then integrate the magnetic field to get the total magnetic energy: $$W_m=\frac{4 \pi}{9} \mu_0 \sigma^2\omega^2 R^5 ,$$ $\sigma$ is the surface charge density and then : Conservation of energy requires $\frac{dW_m}{dt}= N \omega$, with $N$ constant we get $t=\frac{W_m}{N\omega}$

**My question:** Why did they, in the integration take $\omega$ as constant? My idea was that the sphere is rotating, we then apply a torque which is slowly stopping the spinning of the sphere, as a result we get a induced Electric field $E$, which is trying to "prevent" us from stopping the sphere (that's beside the point), but shouldn't $ \omega$ be $\omega(t)$ ?

Comment: If it is ok, can you show how we get the magnetic energy? I have searched online , but it didnt go well.

Comment: @physicsguy19 http://www.hep.princeton.edu/~mcdonald/examples/rotatingefield.pdf

Also check the references below...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are completely correct. The solution is incorrect. Since $\omega$ is a function of time so is $W$. For convenience we can set $k=\frac{4}{9}\pi \mu_0 \sigma^2 R^5$. Then the equation is $W= k\omega^2$ so

$\dot{W}=2k\omega\dot{\omega}=N\omega$

$\dot{\omega}=N/2k$

Solving that gives a different time than in the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Well you are right, but the total magnetic energy they calculate is dependent on $\omega$, so will return lower energies if it is applied later as $\omega$ reduces to 0.
At *any time* the time differential of this energy will equal the work due to friction, which is also dependent on $\omega$.
(I think you just interpreted the equations incorrectly.)

Comment: But then they integrated the $\int dW_m=\int N\omega dt$ and if $\omega = \omega(t)$  it shouldn't be taken as constant, thats what I meant... They took $\omega$ as constant in the integration over time...